# Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with cdf, $F_X(x)$ and let $Y=F_X^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is a continuous uniform from zero to one. Find cdf of $Y$

Tags: statistics

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with cdf, $F_X(x)$ and let $Y=F_X^{-1}(U)$.The distribution function is strictly increasing on a single interval (which could be infinite, so that the inverse function $F_X^{-1}(y)$ is defined in the natural way.$U$ is a continuous uniform random variable on the interval zero to one. Find cdf of $Y$

So I believe I have the density function of $U$ is $f(x)=1$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

But I'm not sure how to interpret $F_X^{-1}(U)$,

I realize its the inverse of $F_X$ but I don't understand what $U$ is.

Comment: From your own description of the problem, $U$ is a continuous random variable that is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$. Can you clarify what it is about $U$ that you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand how you can apply $F_X^{-1}$ to $U$. Is it $F_X^{-1}(F_U(x))$?

Comment: $U$ is a random variable, taking values between 0 and 1. $F_X$ is a function whose range is the interval $[0,1]$. So, for any real number $z\in[0,1]$, $F_X^{-1}(z)$ gives you whatever real number $w$ is such that $F_X(w)=z$. So $F_X^{-1}(U)$ defines a random variable $W$, such that $F_X(W)=U$.

Comment: Since $X$ is a continuous random variable $F_X^{-1}$ exists giving unique values except possibly on a subset of $[0,1]$ of measure $0$

Comment: @Ceph I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do then to find $F_Y(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\lambda = 1)$ so that
$F_X(u) = 1 - e^{-u}.$ Then, after a little algebra
one has $F_X^{-1}(u) = -\ln(1-u).$

If you let $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ then
$F_X^{-1}(U) \sim \mathsf{Exp}(1).$

This is a method for simulating a random variable $X$ by inverting its CDF (if feasible), and then transforming
a standard uniform random variable $U$ according to
the inverse CDF of of $X,$ sometimes known as the
*quantile function* of $X.$ [The output of a satisfactory pseudorandom number generator is essentially indistinguishable from independent realizations of
a standard uniform random variable.]

Demonstration in R:

```
set.seed(411)    # for reproducibility
u = runif(10^5)  # generate values from UNIF(0,1)
x = -log(1 - u)  # quantile transform to get EXP(1)
hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,1), br = 30, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dexp(x), add=T, col="red", lwd=2, n = 10001)
```

[image]

The first 5000 realizations of $X$ above 
pass a Kolmogorv-Smirnov test for $\mathsf{Exp}(1).$
[The test can't accommodate more than 5000 values.]

```
ks.test(x[1:5000], "pexp", 1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x[1:5000]
D = 0.012407, p-value = 0.4248
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: I dont understand how you get $F_X^{-1}(U)\sim Exp(1)$.

Comment: Illustrated by simulation above. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for discussion. Also search this site for `inverse CDF transform simulation` including [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564584/prove-uniform-distribution/1565517#1565517).

Answer (score 0):

Let's find the CDF of Y. Loosely defined, the CDF is the probability that the random variable takes on a a value less than or equal to some threshold. Let us use the notation of $F_{Y}(y)$ to represent the CDF.
$$CDF_Y = F_{Y}(y)$$
$$= P(Y\le y)$$
$$=P(F_X^{-1}(U) \le y)$$
As the CDF is monotonically increasing, the inequality is preserved when we apply the CDF in the following step
$$=P( U \le F_X(y))$$
Now, if we rewrite this inequality, we can see that this equation represents a Uniform CDF
$$=F_U(F_X(y))$$
Now, taking the parameters of U from your description, we have U ~ Uniform(0,1) which yields the following interpretation for $F_U$:

$$
F_U(F_X(y))= \begin{cases} 
                 0       &\text{ if } F_X(y) \lt 0
              \\ F_X(y)  &\text{ if } 0 \le F_X(y) \lt 1
              \\ 1       &\text{ if } F_X(y) \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$

Because we know $F_X(y)$ is a CDF, and CDFs only take values from $[0,1]$, we can collapse the previous piecewise definition down to

$$F_U(F_X(y)) = F_X(y)$$

Pulling down the initial part of the equation, we have

$$F_Y(y) = F_X(y)$$

and thus

$$Y \sim X $$